# Node Grunt.js 'Warning: connect is not defined Use '

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gruntjs

I am making a basic grunt file to start my express.js server. I know there is a plugin just for that, but for learning purposes I want to do it by hand. I am getting a connect not defined message when I run grunt. However, it's defined as far as I can tell.

Error message:

```
one@localhost ~/app/yo $ grunt 
Running "default" task
Warning: connect is not defined Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
one@localhost ~/app/yo $
```

Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        watch: {
            servedFiles: {
                files: '<%= pkg.name %>/static/**',
                options: {
                  livereload: true
                } 
            },
        },

        connect: {
          options: {
            port: 8000,
            hostname: '0.0.0.0',
            livereload: 35729
            },
        },
    });
    grunt.registerTask('default', 'start server', function() {
        grunt.task.run(connect);
    }); 
}
```

Grunt modules:

```
one@localhost ~/app/yo $ lr node_modules/
total 68k
drwxr-xr-x 8 one users  8 Apr 26 17:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 one users  7 Apr 26 18:23 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 one users  3 Apr 25 21:11 .bin
drwxr-xr-x 5 one users 13 Apr 25 21:11 express
drwxr-xr-x 5 one users  9 Apr 26 17:54 grunt
drwxr-xr-x 4 one users  7 Apr 26 17:54 grunt-contrib-connect
drwxr-xr-x 4 one users  7 Apr 26 17:54 grunt-contrib-watch
drwxr-xr-x 3 one users  6 Apr 25 21:37 load-grunt-tasks
one@localhost ~/app/yo $
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because `connect` isn't being defined as a variable:

```
grunt.task.run(connect);
//             ^ ReferenceError
```

It can be used as a one if it's declared first:

```
var connect = 'connect';
```

But, it should otherwise be a `String` value that Grunt can use to find the registered task:

```
grunt.task.run('connect');
```

Comment: You can also use this shorter syntaxe `grunt.registerTask('default', ['connect']);`